# How to use only `handleAsync` to handle non-async exceptions as well?

Tags: java, asynchronous, exception, completable-future

Java's `handleAsync` will not handle exceptions which don't come from a completion stage, for example:

```java
package my.package;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

public class Test {

  private CompletableFuture<String> throwWithoutCompletionStage() {
    throw new RuntimeException("error");
  }

  private CompletableFuture<String> getName() {
    // calls external API, does some work then throws
    throwWithoutCompletionStage();
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture("name");
  }

  public CompletableFuture<String> process() {
    return getName()
        .thenApplyAsync(result -> {
          // do something
          return result;
        })
        .handleAsync((result, exception) -> {
          if (exception != null) {
            return result;
          } else {
            return null;
          }
        });
  }
}
```

When `process` is called `handleAsync` will not be executed but rather the exception will be propagated to `process`'s caller which is a bit confusing because one would think that `handleAsync` would catch the exception. So in this case I would also need to wrap `process` in try/catch to really catch all exceptions which looks weird in my opinion and is also error-prone: we need to always remember to wrap methods which return `CompletableFuture` in both `handleAsync` and try/catch.

Is there a best practice to prevent this double exception catching? One solution I thought of is to call `supplyAsync` which would create a completion stage and then use `handleAsync` on it:

```java
  public CompletableFuture<CompletableFuture<String>> process() {
     return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> getName())
        .handleAsync((result, exception) -> {
          if (exception != null) {
            return null;
          } else {
            return result;
          }
        });
  }
```

The problem with this code is that now `process` return type is `CompletableFuture<CompletableFuture<String>>` but also this seems redundant to wrap code in `supplyAsync` solely in order to have `handleAsync` catch all exceptions.

Comment: Is changing `getName()` an option?

Comment: @Holger it depends what did you have in mind?

Comment: The simplest solution is to put `throwWithoutCompletionStage();` in a `try … catch …` block, as returning a future but doing the actual work (including potentially throwing an exception) outside it, looks like a flawed design. If you return an already completed future in the successful case, you should return an already (exceptionally) completed future in the failed case. Of course, you could also create a new method fixing the issue by wrapping the `getName()` call, but this shouldn’t be necessary for a `private` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don’t want to change the behavior of the `getName()` method, you have to use something like

```java
public CompletableFuture<String> process() {
  return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::getName, Runnable::run)
      .thenCompose(Function.identity())
      .thenApplyAsync(result -> {
        // do something
        return result;
      })
      .handleAsync((result, exception) -> {
        if (exception != null) {
          return result;
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      });
}
```

By using `Runnable::run` as `Executor` you ensure that the “async” operation is executed immediately in the caller thread, just like the direct invocation of `getName()` would do. Using `.thenCompose(Function.identity())`, you get a `CompletableFuture<String>` out of the `CompletableFuture<CompletableFuture<String>>`.

However, if `getName()` returns a completed future in the successful case, it should also return a future in the exceptional case. This may look like

```java
private CompletableFuture<String> getName() {
  try {
    throwWithoutCompletionStage();
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture("name");
  } catch(Throwable t) {
    return CompletableFuture.failedFuture(t);
  }
}
```

[`failedFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#failedFuture(java.lang.Throwable)) has been introduced in Java 9. If you need a Java 8 compatible solution, you have to add such a factory method to your code base

```java
public static <U> CompletableFuture<U> failedFuture(Throwable ex) {
  CompletableFuture<U> f = new CompletableFuture<>();
  f.completeExceptionally(ex);
  return f;
}
```

Or you integrate this logic into the `getName()` method:

```java
private CompletableFuture<String> getName() {
  CompletableFuture<String> result = new CompletableFuture<>();
  try {
    throwWithoutCompletionStage();
    result.complete("name");
  } catch(Throwable t) {
    result.completeExceptionally(t);
  }
  return result;
}
```